# Angular 4 - Activated Route with param

Tags: angular, parameters, router

I have a list page and a detail page. Selecting an item from the list page will route to the details page.

routing module:

```
const itemRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'item', component: ItemListComponent},
    { path: 'item/:id', component: ItemDetailComponent  }
];
```

list component:

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

goToDetail(item) {
    this.router.navigate(['item'], {id: item.id});
}
```

Problem:
Selecting an item goes to this url: 
http://localhost:3000/item/2

But the browser shows "Not found" error.

On the console, I see this:

```
:3000/item/2:1 GET http://localhost:3000/item/2 404 (Not Found)
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/item/2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.router.navigate(['item', item.id])`?

Comment: Still having the same issue - "Not found".

Comment: Do you refresh the page after the navigation, or do you just navigate?

Answer (score 12):

I think the issue was that I had this on the html for the list page:

```
<a href="item/{{item.id}}">{{item.id}}</a>
```

I changed it to:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/item', item.id]">{{item.id}}</a>
```

and removed this from the component:

```
goToDetail(item) {
    this.router.navigate(['item'], {id: item.id});
}
```

This worked!

Comment: Correction: Square bracket misplaced.
    this.router.navigate(['item', {id: item.id}]);

Answer (score 2):

Your routes are well defined. But you have 3 basics ways to redirect: **href**, **routerLink** and **router.navigate**.

---

### The classic href property in a HTML anchor tag

This one is *outside* Angular control. In the template (*html file*) of your *Item* **List** component you could add the simple anchor html tag:

```
<a href="...an static url..">Text of this link</a>
```

But, because this way is outside Angular control, you should use this solution maybe for outside perdurable static urls. Like a Google Page, Facebook Page, etc.

*So, in this scenario*: The user interacts with your DOM and your DOM will fire an event making your **browser** to redirect you.

### Using routerLink attribute

This solution **requires** the **RouterModule** imported in some way to your actual ngModule to work. The most basic way to do this, in your main module (Commonly *app.module.ts*) you should need to add:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

And, add *RouterModule* inside the imports array in your *@NgModule* decorator.

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ....,
    RouterModule,
    ....
  ],
  ...
})
```

Then in the *template* of your *ItemListComponent*, you could reference to an *static path*, or *generate one dynamically*.

**To reference a static path**, you only need to add the **routerLink** *attribute* with your path as a value:

```
<... routerLink="/item">If you click this element, you will be redirected to ItemListComponent</...>
```

*Note: `<...></...>` means that the tag you use doesn't matter at all if its rendered in your page.*

**To reference a generated link**, for example `model/item/4`, you need to add the **routerLink** *attribute* as an *input* (Between `[]`), and an array of path segments which contains each segment in a *sequencial* order:

```
<... [routerLink]="['/model', 'item', item.id]">...</...>
```

Being *item* an accesible *object* on your template (public variable inside the class component *OR* a variable declared in the template like using `*ngFor="let item of items"`) with an *id* as a property.

*Note: You could simplify that link using `[routerLink]="['/model/item', item.id]"`, because `/model/item` is **static** in the url.*

*So, in this scenario*: The user interacts with your DOM, your DOM will call the *RouterModule*, and this last one will end looking for a match inside your routes making **Angular** to redirect you.

### Using the method navigate from Router class.

This solution *aditionally* **requires** the **Router** *imported and injected* in the component you want to handle the route (*ItemListComponent* in this case - *ItemList.component.ts* file).

To import the Router, add this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

To inject it; add it to the *constructor*:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Then, add the *method* you want to handle the redirection in your class, like the one you added:

```
goToDetail(item) {
    this.router.navigate(['/item', item.id]);
}
```

And lastly, you should need to add in your *template* an event which will call your function. For example:

```
<... (click)="goToDetail(item)">...</...>
```

*So, in this scenario*: The user interacts with your DOM, your DOM fires an event which will fire a method on your class which will call the method *navigate* from *Router* class, which will end looking finally for a match inside your routes making **Angular** to redirect you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different types of parameters you can use with Angular: `required`, `optional`, and `query` parameters.

For managing ids on a detail page as you have in your example, you most likely want to use `required` parameters.

Your configuration for `required` parameters is correct.

But your navigation to the parameter is using the `optional` parameter syntax.

Change it to:

```
this.router.navigate(['item', item.id]);
```

`Required` parameters need to be defined within the array.

For a detailed discussion of the three different types of parameters, check out this Pluralsight course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing

Comment: I have changed it to the same array, still having the same issue. "Not found"

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

this.router.navigate(['item'+item.id]);